# When a process will go to 'D' state?

Tags: linux, process, io

I'm using 
"Linux hostname 2.6.28-15-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 18 18:40:08 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux"

All the client machines will use Thin-client ,I will use my laptop for working and I will
mount my home directory from server to my laptop.

If I open the firefox in my laptop  the firefox window will not open  because the process
is in 'D' state, and all other users machines got hang up
and the lockd process is in 'D' state,

ps ajx | grep firefox

```
1  6187  4313  4313 ?   -1 D<    1030   3:16 /usr/lib/firefox-3.5b4pre/firefox-3.5

   7610  7622  7621  7610 pts/3      7621 S+    1030   0:00 grep firefox
```

if I check the syslog

> Jul 13 10:35:56 hostname kernel: [222583.872059] lockd: cannot monitor
>   laptop
>
> Jul 13 10:35:57 hostname kernel: [222583.872059] lockd: cannot monitor
>   laptop

ps ajx | grep lockd

> root      9178  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D<   13:35   0:00
>   [lockd]
>
> root     11039  0.0  0.0   3340   796 pts/3    S<+  14:18   0:00 grep
>   lockd

The same message for all the client machines.

When a process will goes to 'D' state?

When the lockd process will go to 'D' state?

What is the purpose of lockd process.

Answer (score 40):

[It means "uninterruptible sleep"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5648/117549).

```
D    Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
```

In this state, a process doesn't wake up right away to process signals. When doing device `I/O` it's the only way to go (otherwise data corruption could result).

Answer (score 34):

**`D` state** code means that process is in **uninterruptible sleep**.

- usually this is due to I/O.
- `lockd` is in-kernel daemon that manages NFS locking.

Probably, your problem has to do with NFS communication.

Comment: how to avoid this ? the lockd process should not go to 'D' state, what I need to do ?

Comment: @ungalnanban: It is impossible, processes always go in and out of 'D' if using I/O. So in your case process is trying to, for example, read or write some data, acquire a lock, cannot do that and keeps waiting. You have to debug what it is waiting for etc. I am not an NFS expert to tell that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what the other answers say, D state doesn't necessarily mean that a task is uninterruptible. For example, many D state processes will, in fact, exit on terminal signals. You can read some examples of using that for testing [in this article](https://chrisdown.name/2024/02/05/reliably-creating-d-state-processes-on-demand.html).

In Linux, many D states are entered with the `TASK_KILLABLE` flag set:

```
linux % git grep -ihc _killable | paste -sd+ | bc
539
```

`TASK_KILLABLE` was created because -- while in some cases we do actually need to shield the process from any signal interaction at all -- in some cases it's fine as long as we know the process will terminate with no more userspace instructions executed. For example, in D states where DMA is not being performed (for example, `vfork()`), we have to block in order to prevent some unsafe operating condition, but there's no reason for us to continue to wait if the next thing we're going to do is simply terminate – it's a waste of time and of a process.

Instead of being fully uninterruptible, with `TASK_KILLABLE`, when we receive a signal we check if the signal is fatal (that is, it's either a non-trappable fatal signal, or the program has no userspace handler for a signal with a default terminal disposition), and if it is, we terminate the process without allowing it to execute any more userspace instructions.

All a D state process represents is a process which cannot execute any more userspace instructions, but blocking all signals is only one interpretation of how to achieve that, and it's not necessary in all circumstances.