# What are some other reasons for process being in D state except performing I/O?

Tags: signals

I have been recently asked this question during interview, "What is `D` state and when does process goes in `D` state. I explained what `D` state is and then gave the answer that when the process is performing `I/O` operation that is when its in `D` state.

The interviewer (its on of the high tech companies in the world) said that there is other reason when process goes in `D` state, what reason could that be, but I couldn't think of anything else.

This answer [When a process will go to 'D' state?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16738/when-a-process-will-go-to-d-state) also explains its usually I/O which sends a process in `D` state, which I understand clearly.

Can someone please tell me what are some other reasons for process being in D state except performing I/O?

Comment: More precisly, the process is *waiting* for the signal of the end of an IO operation

Answer (score 1):

A process can go into uninterruptible sleep when performing synchronization tasks, such as trying to obtain a mutex lock.