# Reason for the inability of root to send a fatal signal to PID 1/init

Tags: root, kill

Why can't root send a fatal signal to PID 1/`init` process (`sudo kill -9 1`)?

As stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5648/20447).

Comment: Because it is a dangerous way to reboot the system.

Comment: couldn't the kernel spawn another, as soon as it detects the absence of one?

Comment: @hus787 It could, but the only process the kernel spawns is `init` (or nowadays, an `init` replacement).  `init` takes care of spawning processes.  There isn't really a reason to kill `init`.

Comment: @kurtm there is one: suppose you log into your remote system and realize you have an attacker there. Before you manage to do anything else, *he* realizes you know of his presence and issues `rm -Rf /`. In that case kernel panic is the best way to save as much data as possible - `kill -9 1` is (or would be) the only fast way to trigger one *remotely*. I actually believe it was possible on Linux years ago. (/me is not in the mood of looking that up now.)

Comment: Interesting reading about implementation on Linux: http://flossstuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/why-you-cant-kill-init/

Comment: @peterph went through that link before I posted here.

Comment: @peterph For that case a `halt` that didn't do all the graceful shutdown stuff (which used to be common but is rare now) would be a better bet.  The only reason that Linux kernel panicked in the referred article is essentially because the author didn't take out all of init's special-case protections.  And if the attacker has root, he could easily block your kill.  It would be more interesting to see what started going wrong if you could kill init without all the special casing.