# What prevents a reboot?

Tags: linux, reboot

On Linux, how can I track what prevents a reboot of the system after issuing it via `sudo reboot`?

I always thought that this caused switching the runlevel and in the end the reboot, but now I was stumped when several times the machines hadn't rebooted after being told to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem once when my system was running uninterruptible processes. We went into a very nasty situation, where our Apache processes were seemingly waiting for something from the disk, and [couldn't be killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptable-process).

As far as I know, when shutting down, Linux sends `SIGTERM`s to its processes, and a `SIGKILL` a few seconds later for those who dared disobey. However, the kernel itself will protect these processes if they are in uninterruptible state: this helps preventing data loss when the hanging system call involves an I/O operation. Right now, I can't really think of anything else capable of *discarding*<sup>*</sup> a `SIGKILL`, so other elements of answer could be brought here.

<sup>* this is a rather simplified (if not erroneous) way to see it, and it does not take signal asynchronicity into account. See Gilles' comment for more details on this point.</sup>

However, when it comes to uninterruptible processes...

> How to kill an uninterruptible process without rebooting: somehow make the system call terminate. **Frequently the most effective manner to do this without hitting the power switch is to pull the power cord.** You can also become a kernel hacker and make the driver use TASK_KILLABLE, as explained in [the LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/288056/).

You can get a list of all running uninterruptible processes with...

```
$ ps -eo 'state,pid,args' | awk '$1 == "D" {print;}'
$ ps -eo 'state,pid,args' | grep -E '^D'
$ ps -eo 'state,pid,args' | egrep '^D'
...
```

Comment: A SIGKILL is never discarded. It can be delayed indefinitely if a syscall is hanging, but if the syscall is eventually unblocked then the process will die at that point. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work