# How to terminate a process when kill -9 doesn't work?

Tags: linux, kill

I've seen a few cases of processes that don't respond to kill -9.

Most recently, I've seen both lsusb and reaper get stuck and be unresponsive to kill -9. (After trying all the usual signals first) How do I tell Linux to kill the process no matter what?

Comment: Try to remove (if it's applicable) USB devices from the computer.

Comment: A related question is of course https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/195998/5132 .