# How to force a PID to terminate?

Tags: process, kill, process-management, pkill

Yes, I've tried all the basic `kill`, `pkill`, etc. methods that come up with a Google search.
Sometimes it works, other times it seems something is preventing the process from terminating.
There is no `stderr` message when the `kill` command fails, but `ps`, `pgrep`, etc. show the process is still running.

Is there a more forceful way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: First thing I tried. I thought it would work too, but no such luck in this instance, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, what happened when you tried? Did you get an error message? Nothing? What does the output of `ps` show for this process? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: @terdon yep, that info's already included in the question body. The command executed, without error. It appeared to be successful, but I noticed the (non-responsive) process in question was still running. Confirmed by `pgrep`, and also `ps aux`. Wouldn't even let me do a clean reboot. It's not the first time I've encountered this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, but can you please show us the output of `ps` so we can see what it reports for the process? Also, if you've tried `kill -9` and that also fails, add that to your question too. The more detail you give, the more likely it is that we'll be able to answer.

Comment: @terdon No, I can't.

Answer (score 5):

`kill -KILL $PID` or `kill -9 $PID` will forcibly terminate `$PID`, unless you don't have the permissions to do so (i.e., it belongs to a different user and you're not root), but be very careful with it. Inflicting it on a process will prevent it from doing any kind of filesystem (or other) cleanup.

Comment: It's worth remembering that `kill -9` might not always stop the process in the time frame you would like - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work

Comment: Yep, tried that.