# kill -9 cannot kill process with parent PID = 1

Tags: root, kill

I have a process with parent PID = 1.

The command `kill -9 382` doesn't work. I am root.

What can I do?

```
root       382     1  0 07:29 ?        00:00:00 dsmrecall /ptstv/HVideo/2014/2014761/G201476100010007.mxf
```

Comment: Maybe this will explain everything: [What if 'kill -9' does not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work)

Comment: What is the exact error message that `kill` returns?  If there is none, then most likely the process is `defunc`.  Unless you have any idea why that is, which seems unlikely, the simplest solution is to restart the system.  I would be tempted to assume that another important relevant process was killed improperly.

Answer (score 1):

The owner of the process is `root` hence you should execute the `kill` command as user `root`.

You can do it by running:

```
sudo kill -9 382
```

Or in two steps:

1. turn to be `root` using one of the below options:

   - `su -`
   - `sudo su -`
   - `sudo -i`
2. `kill` the process as user `root`:

   kill -9 382

[man su](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)

```
   su allows to run commands with a substitute user and group ID.

   When called without arguments, su defaults to running an interactive
   shell as root.
```

[More info about sudo vs su](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376199/sudo-su-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bin-bash-when-does-it-matter-which-is-used)

Comment: The second option is not always possible. Better use `sudo su -`

Comment: @RomeoNinov - thanks for the comment! updated my answer

Comment: `sudo su -`? What's the purpose of that?

Comment: @coutermode agreed, you should use sudo -i instead.

Comment: Actually, I am already login with root. Is there something wrong with my system?

Comment: @HsingYi - what do you mean `kill -9` doesn't work? what happened when you execute the command as `root`?

Comment: @Yaron - I am already root, and **kill -9 382** doesn't work, the process still exist.