# Kill running process

Tags: kill, top, process-management, gpu, htop

I own some old processes on a shared compute server. They consume a lot of CPU and according to `htop` they're in the **running**-state:

```
PID   USER   PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
21420 <user> 20   0  0.278t  48776  34012 R  53.3  0.0  22254:28 extract_image_f
```

where `<user>` is my user name.

I tried `kill -9 21420`, without any effect (return code is `0`). 
[They say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work) that `kill -9` always works for running processes if I have sufficient permission.
They also say it might take a while for this to be effective, however, I've waited for 4 weeks now.
I'm pretty sure that I have sufficient rights to kill my own processes, though I didn't check that (how do I?). I'm not the admin of the server.

What can I do if restarting is not an option? What's going on here?

Edit: Long ago, the process used the GPU (CUDA via keras). Maybe something went wrong there? According to `nvidia-smi`, the GPU is not used by the process anymore.

Comment: Did you try  `kill -15 21420`

Comment: Try also `kill -TERM -1` ; then tell the system administrator

Comment: both commands return 0 and don't affect the status of the process.

Comment: The admin eventually replied: "These processes are stuck in the kernel. Only a reboot can solve this".

Comment: There are a few things that can cause a process to refuse to die, the most common of which is a loss of disk access, usualy over a NFS share or something. The kernel will halt the process and wait forever on the handle to become available again, the only solution is to reboot.