# Unable to kill process with kill -KILL

Tags: kill

I am miffed... This should work. I am using AWS and inside of a docker image but I would still expect this to work:

```
root@1e896e1e9c8e:~/shipamax/server# pgrep -d " " -f ^chromedriver
924
root@1e896e1e9c8e:~/shipamax/server# sudo kill -KILL 924
root@1e896e1e9c8e:~/shipamax/server# pgrep -d " " -f ^chromedriver
924
```

top's report of the process is:

```
   924 root      20   0       0      0      0 Z   0.0  0.0   0:00.27 chromedriver
```

Comment: Perhaps [What if 'kill -9' does not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/86440) would be better.

Comment: I have tried -9 too.

Comment: I have and marked as a duplicate :) It was the ghost process

Comment: Sorry, I realise since you accepted the duplicate you’d read the chosen duplicate thoroughly; I misunderstood your comment wrt. to other `kill -9` answer above.