# How to kill quiesce frozen process?

Tags: bash, kill

```
$ ps ax | grep process
73849   ??  ?E     0:00.00 (process name)
75882   ??  ?E     0:00.00 (process name)
```

I have tried all the solution but it was impossible.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Yes. It's from macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever process you want to end, the process should not be able to resist `sudo kill -9 <PID here>`. The argument `-9` issues a `SIGKILL`, that processes should not be able to intercept.

Use with care, this is not a preferable solution in the common case.

If this does not work for you either, have a look at [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/53092).

Comment: Next time use link from share link ;-) Link from url bar are not permanent and can change anytime. Share link are permanent.