# Why is there output of ping after it has been terminated?

Tags: process, ping, output

When a process breaks, as I know no output will be return anymore. But always after breaking `ping` command we have the statistics of the execution, and as I know it's part of the output.

```bsh
amirreza@time:~$ ping 4.2.2.4
PING 4.2.2.4 (4.2.2.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=95.8 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=92.3 ms
^C
--- 4.2.2.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 92.321/94.052/95.783/1.731 ms
amirreza@time:~$
```

How does it work?

Comment: "When a process breaks, as I know no output will be return anymore." [citation needed]  This is false.

Comment: That thing you know, it just ain’t so.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> makes the terminal send SIGINT to the foreground process group. A process that receives SIGINT can do anything, it can even ignore the signal. A common reaction to SIGINT is to exit gracefully, i.e. after cleaning up etc.

Your `ping` is simply *designed* to print statistics upon SIGINT and then to exit.

Other tools may or may not exit upon SIGINT at all. E.g. a usual behavior of an interactive shell (while not running a command) is to clear its command line and redraw the prompt.

SIGINT is not the only signal designed to terminate commands. See the manual ([`man 7 signal`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)), there are many signals whose default action is to terminate the process. `kill` sends SIGTERM by default. SIGTERM is not SIGINT. Both can be ignored. [SIGKILL cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5648/108618), but it should be your last choice.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi The default action of the SIGINT signal is to kill the process. But the process can override this default.

Comment: @Barmar, same with SIGTERM

Comment: @JoelFan True, but what does that have to do with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, `ping` is quite special because it doesn't follow the [WCE](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) as expected by bash -- which would require it to kill itself with `SIGINT` after handling the signal instead of terminating via `_exit(2)`. This could be easily demonstrated by trying to break out with Ctrl-C from this loop: `while ping www.google.com; do :; done` when run from bash vs. when run from other shell like dash which doesn't follow the WCE thing.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi if by chance your problem was not being to break out of `ping` when called in a bash loop, you can use `awk` as a wrapper: `xawk(){ awk "BEGIN{system(\"$*\")}"; }; ...; while xawk ping www.google.com; do :; done` => will promptly die after the first Control-C, no need to keep it pressed ;-) (I've seen this in some answer here -- but I'm not able to find it now).

Comment: @user414777 Actually `ping` does obey WCE.  To it, Ctrl-C is a request to perform a normal exit of the otherwise infinite loop, thus it exits with a normal status, not a signal.  This causes `bash` to correctly continue running additional commands in a script.  (Not that you would typically run ping this way in a script anyway.)

Comment: @Miral that's just a post-hoc rationalization. `ping`'s behaviour predates that WCE thing. And as seen from many questions here and elsewhere, people expect a Ctrl-C to kill both the ping and the script it was called from (which is exactly what happens in non-WCE respecting shells).

Comment: My examples were not the best, but fwiw, it's not only a problem in loops and not only when ping returns a non-zero status. E.g. `bash -c 'ping 10.13.13.13; echo YEAH $?'`, a Control-C will continue with the echo instead of cutting short the whole thing (as most users, rightly or wrongly, would expect).

Comment: I disagree that most users should expect that.  It's no different from running `nano` or another interactive editor and using whatever command that provides to perform a normal exit.  It just so happens that in the case of `ping` that it uses Ctrl+C to request a normal exit, that's all.

Comment: @Miral You may "disagree" as much as you want, but that doesn't change the fact that people expect it, and this looks very much like a POLA violation. Notice that this is NOT a pet-peeve of mine -- I rarely if ever write bash scripts, but I'm familiar with this problem from many questions here and elsewhere (which are usually mis-analyzing it and placing the blame somewhere else). Also, neither `nano` nor any other editor I know of is doing a normal exit upon catching `SIGINT`; most of them (like `ed`) will cancel the current command *without* exiting when in some kind of "line" mode.

Answer (score 4):

Additional to the accepted answer - here's ping running in one session, and in another I ran different kill commands.

```
server~ $ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.5.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from google.com(172.217.5.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=111 time=1.68 ms
64 bytes from google.com(172.217.5.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=111 time=1.73 ms
Terminated
```

The above was a **SIGTERM**, which is signal 15.  The exit code was 143.

```
server ~ $ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.5.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from google.com(172.217.5.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=111 time=1.71 ms
64 bytes from google.com(172.217.5.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=111 time=1.71 ms
Killed
```

This was a **SIGKILL**, which is signal 9.  Visually it looks the same, but with a different text, and the exit code is 137 this time.

```
server~ $ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.5.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from google.com(172.217.5.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=111 time=1.69 ms
64 bytes from google.com(172.217.5.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=111 time=1.70 ms
           **signal sent here**
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.697/1.701/1.705/0.004 ms
```

This was a **SIGINT** which is signal 2.  So functionally the same as a `^C` Curiously the exit code is 0 which to most tests will be a success, as opposed to a failure.

The upshot of this is that `ping` does different things for different signals.

You can see a source file for ping at https://gist.github.com/kbaribeau/4495181 which references [https://ftp.arl.army.mil/~mike/ping.html](https://ftp.arl.army.mil/%7Emike/ping.html)  as the original.

```
line
408     signal( SIGINT, finish );
409     signal(SIGALRM, catcher);

457     *           C A T C H E R
459     * This routine causes another PING to be transmitted, and then
460     * schedules another SIGALRM for 1 second from now.
```

See the link for the full code.