# How can I kill a process in Linux when kill -9 fails?

Tags: nvidia, kill, gpu, zombie-process

I have a process (actually a pair of them) numbered 1234 which uses my NVIDIA GPUs. I want to kill it. I tried `kill 1234`; I tried `kill -9 1234` I tried `kill -KILL 1234` - no effect. Tried Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Z in the terminal session where the process is running - no effect. I tried killing as root - no effect. Or rather, there is some effect: The process state is no Z(ombie). But it still seems to use ~100% CPU.

Can I "kill it harder" somehow?

Notes:

- The process is interacting with the CUDA driver. Trying to tell my GPU to power down then power up (using nvidia-smi) also has no effect.
- Power-cycling the machine works :-(

Comment: Related: [What if 'kill -9' does not work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642)

Comment: @Kusalananda: Indeed, but my process does not seem to have quit, and is consuming resources - supposedly contradicting the answers there.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5642/what-if-kill-9-does-not-work

Comment: Driver bug? There is uninterruptible code. However this is only in the kernel. I think there were attempts to minimise it. So probably in a driver.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: Very possible. Question is, can I get around it? It turns out all subsequent processes interacting with the GPU also hang.

Comment: @chronic.kernel.panic: Yeah, what that page says is not useful in this case.